# Member Variable Type Based on L or R Value Template

Tags: c++, templates

I am trying to either store a reference member variable or a move constructed value member variable based on if either an l or r value was passed to the function. Here is what I have tried. Is there any guidance on how to get the functionality I want?

### Attempt 1

```
template <class T>
struct ARR
{
    ARR(T o) : obj(std::forward(o)) {}

    typename std::conditional<std::is_lvalue_reference<T>::value, std::decay<T>::type &, std::decay<T>::type>::type obj;
};

template <class T>
void make_ARR(T && o)
{
    ARR<decltype(o)> t(std::forward(o));
}
```

### Attempt 2

```
template <class T>
struct ARR
{
};

template <class T>
struct ARR <T &&>
{
    ARR(T o) : obj(std::move(o)) {}
    typename std::decay<T>::type obj;
};

template <class T>
struct ARR <T &>
{
    ARR(T o) : obj(o) {}
    typename std::decay<T>::type & obj;
};

template <class T>
void make_ARR(T && o)
{
    ARR<decltype(o)> t(std::forward(o));
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Examining the end result of the following in a debugger seems to indicate that this is what you're looking for, even though the class's semantics may not be exactly what you are after.

```
template<bool> class val_or_ref;

template<>
class val_or_ref<false> {

public:

    template<typename T>
    struct ARR {

    public:
        T obj;

        ARR(T &&value) : obj(std::move(value)) {}
    };

    template<typename T>
    static ARR<T> make(T &&t)
    {
        return ARR<T>(std::forward<T>(t));
    }
};

template<>
class val_or_ref<true> {

public:

    template<typename T>
    struct ARR {

    public:
        T &obj;

        ARR(T &value) : obj(value) {}
    };

    template<typename T>
    static ARR<T> make(T &t)
    {
        return ARR<T>(t);
    }
};

template<typename T>
auto make_ARR(T &&t)
    -> decltype(val_or_ref<std::is_lvalue_reference<T>::value>
            ::make(std::forward<T>(t)))
{
    return val_or_ref<std::is_lvalue_reference<T>::value>
        ::make(std::forward<T>(t));
}
```

With the above, the results from the following:

```
int n=4;

auto a=make_ARR(7);
auto b=make_ARR(n);
```

`gdb` tells me that:

```
(gdb) p a
$1 = {obj = 7}
(gdb) p b
$2 = {obj = @0x7fffffffe384}
(gdb) p &a
$3 = (val_or_ref<false>::ARR<int> *) 0x7fffffffe380
(gdb) p &b
$4 = (val_or_ref<true>::ARR<int> *) 0x7fffffffe370
(gdb) p b.obj
$5 = (int &) @0x7fffffffe384: 4
```

There might be other, more compact ways of doing that, but this seems to be fairly self-explanatory.

Comment: That is great. You're right it is very clear what is happening here and pretty similar to my attempt. Thanks for the help. Your code really clarifies some concepts for me.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to Sam I worked backward from his code and got a working and compact solution. Thanks for the help, I can see all the problems in my original attempts now.

First, I noticed that the two definitions of ARR were scoped inside the ref_or_val class. I wanted to bring them out and get rid of the ref_or_val class. Next, I compared my forward to Sam's and noticed I was missing the template. And finally, the return values were all being copy constructed so I returned the input's to the constructor to save some overhead.

### Final Code

```
template<typename T>
struct val_ARR
{
    T obj;
    val_ARR(T && value) : obj(std::move(value)) {}
};

template<typename T>
struct ref_ARR
{
    const T & obj;
    ref_ARR(const T & value) : obj(value) {}
};

template<typename T>
auto make_ARR(T && t) -> typename std::conditional<std::is_lvalue_reference<decltype(t)>::value, ref_ARR<T>, val_ARR<T>>::type
{
    return std::forward<T>(t);
}
```

### Intermediate Code

This is the in between step from Sam's code and my final code. I learned a lot from this, especially that when beginning with templates to make small changes and then compile to make sure things are still working.

```
template<typename T>
struct val_ARR
{
    T obj;
    val_ARR(T &&value) : obj(std::move(value)) {}
};

template<typename T>
struct ref_ARR
{
    const T &obj;
    ref_ARR(const T &value) : obj(value) {}
};

template<bool> class val_or_ref;

template<>
struct val_or_ref<false> 
{
    template<typename T>
    static val_ARR<T> make(T &&t)
    {
        return std::forward<T>(t);
    }
};

template<>
struct val_or_ref<true> 
{
    template<typename T>
    static ref_ARR<T> make(const T &t)
    {
        return t;
    }
};

template<typename T>
auto make_ARR(T &&t)  -> decltype(val_or_ref<std::is_lvalue_reference<T>::value>::make(std::forward<T>(t)))
{
    return std::forward<T>(t);
}
```